# unable to remove a data from the sub module array in mongoose data

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a wearied issue. I have a mongoose module which has sub module in it. Below is my schema. Both the child and parent has user data. The problem is when using the condition for fetch data from child module by using the parent user detail.

**Child Schema**

```
const childSchema = new Schema({
participant: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
},
note: {
    type: String
}}, { _id : false });
```

**Parent Schema**

```
const InterviewSessionSchema = new Schema({
status: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
description: {
    type: String,
    required: false
},
organizer: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
},
meetStart: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
},
meetEnd: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
},
participants: [{
    type: childSchema,
    required: true
}]}, { timestamps: true });
```

**My json Data will be**

```
const intreviewSession = { _id: 61d25540ef315a15c8af58cf, status: 'full', description: 'dsfsafa a fsdf sf ', participants: [{ participant: 61ced3019a011977b0bc0432 },{ participant: 61a0af0c20090a40e40d6929 }],organizer: 61ced3019a011977b0bc0432,meetStart: 2022-01-26T01:50:00.000Z,meetEnd: 2022-01-26T02:50:00.000Z,createdAt: 2022-01-03T01:45:36.482Z, updatedAt: 2022-01-03T02:21:19.799Z,  __v: 0}
```

**Query**

```
intreviewSession.participants.find((x)=>x.participant != intreviewSession.organizer);
```

**Actual OP**

```
[{ participant: 61ced3019a011977b0bc0432 },{ participant: 61a0af0c20090a40e40d6929 }]
```

**Expected**

```
[{ participant: 61a0af0c20090a40e40d6929 }]
```

**Query 2**

```
intreviewSession.participants.find((x)=>x.participant != '61ced3019a011977b0bc0432');
```

**Output**

```
[{ participant: 61a0af0c20090a40e40d6929 }]
```

I am not sure what the problem with the query and getting the expected value if I use the query 2.